# Rails asset precompilation happening even if there is no change in assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, aws-opsworks

I am running a rails stack on AWS Opsworks. In before_symlink.rb deploy hook, I have the following code.

```
rails_env = new_resource.environment["RAILS_ENV"]
shared_path = "#{new_resource.deploy_to}/shared"

# create shared directory for assets, if it doesn't exist
directory "#{shared_path}/assets" do
  mode 0770
  action :create
  recursive true
  not_if do
    Dir.exists?("#{shared_path}/assets")
  end
end

# symlink current deploy's asset folder to shared assets each deploy
link "#{release_path}/public/assets" do
  to "#{shared_path}/assets"
end

# precompile assets into public/assets (which is symlinked to shared assets folder)
execute "rake assets:precompile" do
  cwd release_path
  command "bundle exec rake assets:precompile --trace"
  environment 'RAILS_ENV' => rails_env
end
```

The problem is that assets are precompiled all the time even if there is no change, inspite of being in a symlinked shared folder. I am running on Rails 4.1.2 and I guess Rails is intelligent enough to compile only changed assets after Rails 4? Why is this happening?

*UPDATE*

This is now solved.

I missed out symlinking /tmp/cache to /shared/tmp/cache. This is where sprockets stores cached files.

Updated code.

```
# Precompile assets. Assets are compiled into shared/assets and shared between deploys.
rails_env = new_resource.environment["RAILS_ENV"]
shared_path = "#{new_resource.deploy_to}/shared"

# create shared directory for assets, if it doesn't exist
directory "#{shared_path}/assets" do
  mode 0770
  action :create
  recursive true
  not_if do
    Dir.exists?("#{shared_path}/assets")
  end
end

#create shared directory to store sprockets cache
directory "#{shared_path}/tmp/cache" do
  mode 0770
  action :create
  recursive true
  not_if do
    Dir.exists?("#{shared_path}/tmp/cache")
  end
end

# symlink current deploy's asset folder to shared assets each deploy
link "#{release_path}/public/assets" do
  to "#{shared_path}/assets"
end

# symlink current deploy's sprockets cache  folder to shared cache folder on each deploy
link "#{release_path}/tmp/cache" do
  to "#{shared_path}/tmp/cache"
end

# precompile assets into public/assets (which is symlinked to shared assets folder)
execute "rake assets:precompile" do
  cwd release_path
  command "bundle exec rake assets:precompile --trace"
  environment 'RAILS_ENV' => rails_env
end
```

Answer (score 1):

OpsWorks rebuilds your entire rails app upon each deployment and keeps a number of backup copies.  It should create it in a path like:

```
/srv/www/yourappname/current
```

You can confirm this by ssh into your server.  If you go to path

ls -la /srv/www/yourappname/releases

You should see a number of folder with datetime stamps names.
If you look at contents they will each contain your entire rails app.
This makes it easy to roll back if something goes wrong during deployment.

Since each folder is basically a new install of your app, asset pre-compilation needs to happen otherwise the current version won't have any assets.  This type of deployment doesn't just have the same directory do a
`git pull origin master`

UPDATE:  It looks like this was an [issue](https://github.com/rails/sprockets/issues/59) with Sprockets that was resolved in this [pull request](https://github.com/rails/sprockets/pull/89) so make sure your gem sprockets version includes this [commit](https://github.com/rails/sprockets/pull/89/commits/8630ce365b8c09bc6c409263cee2978658097bca).  It looks like it was included in `v4.0.0beta1` & `v4.0.0beta2` so try that or if not, try downgrade to [>=2.12.4 as per this comment](https://github.com/rails/sprockets/issues/59#issuecomment-115875097)

Comment: I understand. But for any "release" folder, my public/assets is symlinked to shared/assets. So it shouldn't matter right? I mean for any release, essentially the assets are residing at a single place.

Comment: This may be true but I believe the default Opsworks deployment scripts run  precompile by default.   See these links for more details.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Ruby_rails.html

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=436400

https://github.com/aws/opsworks-cookbooks/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=before_migrate

Comment: You're a lifesaver. I was already on Sprockets 2.12.4 but I missed out symlinking /tmp/cache to /shared/cache. This is where sprockets stores cached files. I got it from the PR description. Thank you so much :) Now deploy time is under 1 minute.

Comment: Perhaps add your own answer and/or update question with solved and post actual code you changed/added that fixed your issue. Might be helpful for others.